# I don't know how to nest components in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to do something like this in Angular (not Angular JS).

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        This is title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Bla bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Bye bye
    </div>
</div>
```

In angular, I want it to be...

```
<app-main>
    <app-header>This is title</app-header>
    <app-content>Bla bla bla</app-content>
    <app-content>Bye bye</app-footer>
</app-main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you read the [introduction to angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), and the tutorial on the site, as your questions shows you misunderstand a few things about Angular.

Your code on the top works in Angular2+ and in AngularJS as well.

Or you mean you want to build custom components? Also, you can find how to do that on the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components).